# How to read data from Nested Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I am trying to read data from the Javascript array. However, it is saying undefined.

my code is

```
sabhaDetailsArrayTemp.forEach(element => {
  let arra = [];
  console.log(element)
  //return tmp.m_category_name ;
  arra = this.onSabhaChange(element.sabha_name);
  console.log(arra);
  const sabha_typeOBJ = arra.find(x => x.id == 9);
  console.log(sabha_typeOBJ);
  this.procSabhaDetailsArray.push({ sabha_id: element.sabha_name,
      sabha_type: this.newTMPArray.find(x=>x.id == element.sabha_id),
      followup_id:element.followup_id });
});
```

I am assigning array to array. I want to extract object of that `arra`. I tried to use `arra[0]` to access first element then search. However, it returns:

> Error TypeError: Cannot read property find of undefined at
>   edit-contact.component.ts:274

[image: Trying to read data from array]

Comment: A quick heads up, you might want to use `===` than `==`

Comment: Create snippet with sample data to reproduce an issue

Comment: GetSabhaLIstDetailName calls any API?

Comment: `edit-contact.component.ts:274`, is `this.newTMPArray` an array?

Comment: `this.onSabhaChange(element.sabha_name);` is asynchronous, it won't return the array immediately that is why the returned array is empty and `find` is not working. You need to return the `Observable` and then in the `subscribe` you can populate `arra` array.

Comment: What is `newTMPArray`?

Comment: the error refers to the `newTMPArray` property. so check out why that is not initialized. also you should consider using another approach for your `onSabhaChange` method, you can not return from an asynchronous function like that! try to use `async/wait`, `promises` or `callbacks` instead.

Comment: As @AmardeepBhowmick said the call is asynchronous. Using Promise can solve this issue. Use [this link](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) or refer MDN to learn more about promises.

Answer (score 0):

As Amardeep pointed , `this.onSabhaChange(element.sabha_name);` is asynchronous hence JS won't wait for it to get complete and it will keep executing next lines of code(JS is asynchronous in nature).

You need to wait to execute next lines until your service returns the data.

You can implement using Promises. Do below refactoring in your code :

```js
// do following change

onSabhaChange(x) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       
       this.sabhaapicall().subscribe((result)=>{
       
             /// do manipualtion for temp array  : 
              let temparr = result;
             resolve(temparray);
       });  
    });
  }
 
 // and your method 
 
 getSabhaDetailsArra(arr){
 
 ......
 
  this.onSabhaChange(arr).then(value => {
      console.log(`promise result: ${value}`);
       arra = value;
       
       ........
       
       // further lines of code 
    });
    console.log('I will not wait until promise is resolved');
 
 }
```